# INSERT values from .csv into database

Tags: sybase

We have a sybase database running an application our users use which contains client info.

The situation is that address information for maybe 1000 clients or so is out of date. We were given a .csv file with updated address info, and are being asked to update the addresses in the database.

I've filtered the csv to compare the 2 address columns and only show those that are not the same. So I have a .csv containing only the clients who need their address updated.

So imagine this client information lives on a table. We also have unique client ID's to go by along with other personal info found on the client table.

I'm no SQL expert, so my query syntax for sql is probably way off, but does anybody have any suggestions for how I might write a query for this?

Something like,

INPUT FOR EACH [client_id in .csv column A] [address_info in .csv column B] TO clientAddress.table

That's how I imagine it would work in my head anyway. I tried searching around but can't find anybody with a situation similar enough to mine.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  This is a pretty common issue with any list maintenance, but we're going to need a more explicit example.  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see an equivalent example of what you're dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the solution I used. For this example, the updated info to be uploaded is in a file called updatefile.csv. The table is called multi_addresses. Columns in the file being updated in the db are the address, address_2, city, state, etc. Works well for me.

UPDATE multi_addresses, updatefile
SET multi_addresses.address=updatefile.address, 
multi_addresses.address_2=COALESCE(updatefile.address_2, ''), 
multi_addresses.city=updatefile.city, 
multi_addresses.state=updatefile.state, 
multi_addresses.zipcode=updatefile.zipcode
WHERE 
multi_addresses.names_id=updatefile.names_id AND 
multi_addresses.name_location=updatefile.name_location AND 
multi_addresses.addr_type=updatefile.addr_type

SELECT multi_addresses.* FROM multi_addresses 
RIGHT JOIN updatefile ON multi_addresses.names_id=updatefile.names_id AND 
multi_addresses.addr_type=updatefile.addr_type

Answer (score 2):

`USING FILE` clause is used to load data from a file. The column list shows two columns to be imported from the `.csv` file.

```
LOAD TABLE clientAddress.table (client.id, address.info) 
USING CLIENT FILE 'file.csv'
```

Comment: Great thanks so much, I'll give it a shot